# How to recover a query I ran earlier today?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

So basically, I was working on a script this morning and ran it, but then started to edit it, and realized I was making a mistake. When I tried to revert to the earlier script it wouldn't get me back to it. So I searched up and found this script which I tried to run:

```
USE MASTER

SELECT execquery.last_execution_time AS [Date Time]
      ,execsql.text AS [Script]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS execquery
    CROSS APPLY 
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text (execquery.sql_handle) AS execsql
ORDER BY execquery.last_execution_time DESC
```

When I try to Run it, the SELECT is underlined red and I get an error code 1064. Why does this happen?

Comment: A pretty confuse question here. You started off by telling us you worked on something this morning only to continue with a totally different issue. So, what's the question you wanna ask? Pick one. If it is about the query you brought up here then I think it's not MySQL code (`CROSS APPLY` is wrong).

Comment: Try adding a semicolon after `USE MASTER`